# Can we combine this two Lyapunov functions (which imply local stability by separate) to conclude global stability?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Let $x(t)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ constrained to a dynamical system
$$
\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t))
$$
for some vector field $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Moreover, the dynamical system has a unique equilibrium point at the origin.

My goal is to conclude that for this system (with a particular $f$ I have) the origin is globally asymptotically stable. So far, I have found two Lyapunov function candidates $V_1(x),V_2(x)$ which both are positive definite and radially unbounded. Moreover, I managed to show that they comply

1. $\dot{V}_1(x)<0$ $\ \forall x : \|x\|<r_1$
2. $\dot{V}_2(x)<-c$ $\ \forall x : \|x\|>r_2$ and some constant $c>0$
3. $0<r_1<r_2$

If it was the case that $r_1>r_2>0$ instead of item 3), we would be done: global stability follows since item 2) ensures that $x$ reaches $\|x\|\leq r_2$ in finite time from any initial condition, and then one can use 1) to conclude $x$ reaches the origin asymptotically from here.**(as pointed out in the comments, this argument requires nuance, nevertheless, the important part is the following)**. However, from item 3) this is not the case. Thus, I have this disk $r_1<\|x\|<r_2$ in which my Lyapunov stability test is inconclusive. My hope is to show that trajectories $x(t)$ cannot stay in the disk $r_1<\|x\|<r_2$ forever but ultimately reach $\|x\|<r_1$.

**My question is:** from the information given here, do you think is possible to conclude global asymptotic stability either by constructing a new Lyapunov function from $V_1,V_2$ or by checking some condition on $f$ to conclude trajectories cannot stay in $r_1<\|x\|<r_2$?

Indeed, there are many counterexamples in which this is not possible. But my question here is if there is a way to check if it is possible: what properties do you suggest me to check for $f$. I'm looking for suggestions, ideas or relevant bibliography that you think can help me.

**EDIT:** In case this problem is easier, or adds useful information, I can also show the following instead of the original items:

1. $\dot{V}_1(x)<0$ $\ \forall x \in M_1 = \{x : V_1(x)<r_1'\}$
2. $\dot{V}_2(x)<-c$ $\ \forall x \in M_2=\{ V_2(x)>r_2'\}$ and some constant $c>0$
3. $D:=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus(M_1\cup M_2)\neq \emptyset$

We are left to show that there are no invariants in $D$.

**EDIT 2:** After some discussion in the comments, I think the main essence of my question, is more on what happens when the Lyapunov arguments are inconclusive on this non empty set $D$ (bounded, but not containing the origin). A concrete diagram for the state space of what $r_1,r_2,M_1,M_2,D$ looks in the case I am interested is the following:

[image]

Comment: I assume you are trying to show this for a particular system. Did you simulate it for multiple initial conditions with $r_1<\|x(0)\|<r_2$ and did all converge to the origin?

Comment: Yes, I am interested in a particular system. I have made many simulations with those initial conditions and Im very confident it is globally asymthotically stable (it always converge to the origin)

Comment: I am not sure if it is sufficient for your case but you could try the Bendixon criterion to rule out a limit cycle exists in your disk.

Comment: @SampleTime Does that criterion also rule out limit manifolds?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen It only rules out "closed trajectories" AFAIK, but I don't really know what a limit manifold is. I think it is not enough to show stability but it should be a necessary condition: If there is a limit cycle in the disk then the system is not asymptotically stable.

Comment: why not show here the original system and the functions? Are they too lengthy?

Comment: @Arastas Yes, its kind of a mess... i would need to introduce too much context.

Comment: I would say that even $r_1>r_2$ is not sufficient. Generally, it is not enough to say that $\dot{V}_1<0$ to prove that $\|x\|$ remains below $r_1$ as we do not know if the level set of $V_1$ is a circle.

Comment: Totally get your point. I now that this is now different from the original question, but what would you say if changed conditions in items 1 and 2 to $V_1(x)<r_1$ and $V_2(x)>r_2$?

Comment: @FeedbackLooper those level constraints don't mean anything, since one could just multiple each candidate Lyapunov by some positive gain in order to satisfy it.

Comment: Thanks @KwinvanderVeen! I agree. I added a little more detail about that in the question, in case that info is more useful.

Comment: Note that $M_1$ in your plot should be inside the circle $|x|=r_1$, see the explanation in my answer.

Comment: I put $\|x\|=r_1$ inside $M_1$ to comply with the item: $\dot{V}_1(x)<0$ $\ \forall x : \|x\|<r_1$ from my question. By I get your point. There is another $\|x\|=r_3$ which covers $M_3$ as given in your answer. But I as you were saying, maybe these circles are not as important as the sets $M_1,M_2$.

Answer (score 2):

### Bounds on $V$

We start considering the case when we have bounds on the levels of $V$, and we will use these results to study the original question later.

Let us say that there exist $C_1$ such that $\dot{V}_1(x)<0$ for all $x$ such that $V_1(x)>C_1$ and $C_2$ such that $\dot{V}_2(x)<0$ for all $x$ such that $V_2(x)<C_2$. I.e., the $C_1$ constant defines the level set for $V_1$ such that $x$ is converging for large initial conditions, and $C_2$ defines the level set for $V_2$ such that $x$ is converging for small initial conditions. When the system is converging? The intuition is that we need a safe switch from $V_1$ to $V_2$.

#### One way...

Choose an arbitrary small constant $\delta>0$ and define $\Omega = \{x: V_1(x)\le C_1+\delta\}$. From the properties of $V_1$ we know that $x$ reaches $\Omega$ in finite time, and since $V_1$ is radially unbounded, the set $\Omega$ is bounded and contains the origin. Then to prove the convergence we need that $V_2(x)<C_2$ for all $x\in\Omega$. Then for any $x_0\in\Omega$ we have $V_2(x_0)<C_2$ and due to the properties of $V_2$ we conclude that $V_2\to 0$. Note that the trajectory $x$ can leave the set $\Omega$ as it is not invariant.

We need the constant $\delta$ because otherwise, it is possible that $x\to\Omega$ asymptotically and we never switch to $V_2$.

#### ...or another

Another way to see the same idea is to define the set $\mathcal{M} = \{x:V_2(x)<C_2\}$. From the properties of $V_2$ we know that the set $\mathcal{M}$ is invariant ($V_2$ is monotonic decaying for all $x\in\mathcal{M}$ and thus $V_2$ will always remain below $C_2$), contains the origin, and the origin is attractive for all initial conditions in $\mathcal{M}$ since $V_2\to 0$.

Then to prove the convergence we need to show that the set $\Omega = \{x: V_1(x)\le C_1+\delta\}$ lies inside $\mathcal{M}$, $\Omega\subset\mathcal{M}$. Then any initial condition outside $\mathcal{M}$ converges to $\Omega$ (and thus to $\mathcal{M}$) due to the $V_1$ analysis, and for all trajectories starting in $\mathcal{M}$ the origin is attractive due to the $V_2$ analysis.

#### NB

We do not say that $C_1>C_2$ or $C_2>C_1$. What is important is the relation between the sets $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{M}$.

### UPD: Bounds on $x$

Ok, let us see the original question. Suppose there exists $r_1$ such that $\dot{V}_1<0$ for all $\|x\|>r_1$ and $r_2$ such that $\dot{V}_2<0$ for all $\|x\|<r_2$, and $r_2<r_1$. Let us replace $r_1$ with $R_1 = r_1+\delta$, then we know for sure that $x$ enters the ball $\|x\|<R_1$ in finite time. Choose $C_1$ as the largest value of $V_1$ on the boundary $\|x\|=R_1$. Then the set $\Omega=\{x:V_1(x)\le C_1\}$ is attractive and invariant, and the ball $\|x\|<R_1$ lies inside $\Omega$. Note also that the ball $\|x\|\le R_1$ is not necessarily invariant.

Next, choose $C_2$ as the smallest value of $V_2$ on the boundary $\|x\|=r_2$. Then the set $\mathcal{M} = \{x:V_2(x)<C_2\}$ lies inside the ball $\|x\|\le r_2$, this set is invariant and the origin is attractive for all trajectories starting in $\mathcal{M}$.

So what we know at the moment is that the set $\Omega$ is invariant and attractive for all trajectories starting outside of $\Omega$ and that the set $\mathcal{M}\subset \Omega$ is invariant and all trajectories starting in $\mathcal{M}$ converge to the origin.

What is left is the set $\mathcal{D} = \Omega-\mathcal{M}$. As far as I see, it is sufficient to show that no trajectory staring in $\mathcal{D}$ can stay in $\mathcal{D}$, i.e., there are no invariants in $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with your arguments about the relation between $r_1,r_2$, they are not important by themselves. Indeed, the only thing that matters is the relation between $\Omega, \mathcal{M}$. For the first part of your explanation, I agree that if these two sets overlap as you exposed, stability would follow. However, my case is the opposite. I have this non empty set $\mathcal{D}$ for which I want to show that there are no invariants. Unfortunately I failed to expose this correctly in my question, by incorrectly introducing this $r_1,r_2$ values, sorry for that.

Comment: I modified my question at the end, using some of the ideas from here. I think the main point is how to approach the problem of invariants in $\mathcal{D}$. That was the main essence of what I wanted to ask: I have a nonempty set in which my lyapunov arguments are inconclusive. Hopefully, I understood your answer correctly. Thanks!